# How to add composer to an existing drupal 9 site

Tags: composer-php, drupal-9

is there any way to add composer to *existing* site, if it wasn’t downloaded using it?
I’m new to drupal and web-development, so sorry if mu question is stupid.
On drupal.org i’ve read that versions of drupal after 8.8.0 have it pre-installed, but i couldn’t find it. Any help is welcome.

I’ve googled info about it, but couldn’t find nothing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

You can find composer.json and composer.lock files in your drupal directory.
You just need to take them out of that folder and do necessary changes to the file and run "compose install" command.
For example:
modules path
themes path
Docroot path
Sample:
"locations": {
"web-root": "web/"
},